# Why Spark choses to send data over the network in shuffle phase instead of writing to some location on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, cloudera

As far as I understand , spark tries to send data over the network to another node's in memory buffer and spills to disk if it doesn't fit in memory , why can't spark just write to HDFS from where any node can read ?

Comment: First of all HDFS (or any other distributed file system) is not mandatory  component of a Spark cluster. Moreover to make sure that data is accessible locally you would have to strongly couple computing engine and storage. Finally writing to disk is slow, most of the shuffled data has temporary nature, and in case of shuffle intensive task you would need huge amounts of disk space simply to cover data exchange.

Comment: It could be done with HDFS. But why would it? What would be the benefit of HDFS? Shuffle data does not need to be replicated. It does not need to be distributed (it already is).

Answer (score 2):

Writing it to disk is a much slower transfer.
On top of that, you guarantee that you incur the overhead of synchronizing disk access among the interested nodes.